# In App Purchase not restoring transactions with sandbox user

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox

This seems to be a common problem from my research

This is all done on a real device.

My app buys the In App Purchase, but when I come to restore the In App Purchase it does not react.

Following this,

```
    @IBAction func RestoreItem(_ sender: Any) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    print("RESTORING PURCHASES")       
    }
```

it is supposed to call the `products request` then `payment queue` functions.
I have read that if the iTunes Account does not contain the purchases that are not called.
If I run the app and purchase each item the app purchases ok and says these have been purchased before so it knows the purchase history

What I can not understand is why, if it knows the items have been purchased it does not react after calling the function (as seen above).

If I log out of my iTunes Account completely on my device and trigger the action above it asks me to log in to my account. I do this (the same account where I previously purchased) and it does not trigger the `product request` (I have `NSlog` statements all over to see what state I am at)

Any thoughts as i have been struggling with this for days.
thanks

I have included code below, this works for purchasing (just for reference).

```
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive     response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product)
    }

   }


   func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add payment")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error as Any)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.purchased:
            print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
            print(p.productIdentifier)





            let prodID = p.productIdentifier

            switch prodID {
            case "com.clivedancey.social":
                print("Social Reality Unlocked")
                 outBuySocial.setTitle("Social Reality Enabled", for: UIControlState.normal)
                SocialReality()

            case "com.clivedancey.inapp":
                print("MAIN UPGRADE UNLOCKED")

                 outBuyMain.setTitle(" Main Upgrade Complete", for: UIControlState.normal)
                mainunlock()

            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


            queue.finishTransaction(trans)

        case SKPaymentTransactionState.restored:
            print("buy ok, unlock IAP HERE")
            print(p.productIdentifier)


            let prodID = p.productIdentifier

            switch prodID {
            case "com.clivedancey.social":
                print("Social Reality Unlocked")
                outBuySocial.setTitle("Social Reality Enabled", for: UIControlState.normal)

                SocialReality()
                outTransactionLabel.text = " Purchases restored"


            case "com.clivedancey.inapp":
                print("MAIN UPGRADE UNLOCKED")

                outBuyMain.setTitle(" Main Upgrade Complete", for: UIControlState.normal)
                outTransactionLabel.text = " Purchases restored1"
                mainunlock()

            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


            queue.finishTransaction(trans)


        case.failed:
            print("buy error")


            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break

        default:
            print("Default")
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things. First - hopefully not important - is your use of "react" in *but when I come to restore the In App Purchase it does not react*. I hope you *don't* mean that a breakpoint is never hit.

My StoreKit code has two things I'm not seeing in the code you posted.

(1) In `viewDidLoad` I check for purchases and store it:

```
func fetchAvailableProducts()  {
    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
}

public func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        iapProducts = response.products
    }
}
```

Of note is setting the view controller as a delegate - something I don't see in your code. (The logic sounds good though.)

(2) My restore purchases has an extra line of code:

```
func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

Comment: hi ,  ' react ' was changed by an external editor , what i meant was didn't do anything , i have all the extra code in place and buying works fine , but when i restore nothing happens..in the log it says ' nil ' next to where it should say the in app purchase name..maybe its a sandbox user issue...also regarding your code and mine , the product identifier doesn't seem to be recognised when i restore but does when i purchase..

Comment: Glad I didn't interpret the "react" incorrectly. It sounds like you're coding purchases properly, and I'd expect a prompt for login after logging out. Also, I've never had an issue with sandbox users. The only other thing I'm wondering - what if you (1) made a purchase, then (2) deleted the app, then (3) reinstalled the app and tried to restore? That's the scenario I always test for *non-consumable* purchases. You didn't mention trying this - only trying a restore when (maybe) one isn't needed.

Comment: thats fine , yep , tried adding a purchase , deleting the app , re loading from Xcode , then restoring and nada , seems to think a purchase hasn't been made according to the logs , ill keep on slogging at it , thanks for the help. and I've marked your answer as good..cheers

Comment: @clivedancey I just want to apologize for misinterpreting your question when editing, I felt like this was what you meant. Have a good time working on your project :)

Comment: @Devapploper , not a problem my friend

Comment: @dfd i am getting the same problem can you pleas help me i am hitting restore after buying a product but restoring never goes in success.

Comment: @Sandip_Gill, it hard to be of help without seeing your code. In this question/answer I was able to (a) see the OP's code and compare it to mine, then (b) I posted what I saw as important differences. These added up to (1) checking for *all* available products, whether purchased or not, in `viewDidLoad` and (b) an extra line in `restorePurchases`. I also see in the comments I suggested a way to test non-consumable purchases. My answer was accepted so it must have helped, but I honestly cannot say which part actually did. Maybe if you create a new question with your code I could help?